# I can create an H2 database with the H2 Console, but I can't find the database with MMA

Tags: databases

I can create an H2(Server) database using the tool that H2 provides,
[image]

but although i can create a memory based H2 database with the Database Explorer, when I try to create a connection to the H2(Server) database, I can't answer the "Hostname" and "Datebase file" questions shown below:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a 'test' directory in your home directory? I suppose the database will be located there.

Comment: Hostname for a server on your own computer will probably be localhost or 127.0.0.0.

Comment: Correction: I believe the database file may be 'test' itself, located in the home directory.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks. I'll check those suggestions

Comment: Are you sure about the port number BTW?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The razorsql (database manager) help file says that the default port is 9092. I can't find anything about the port number in H2 documentation.

Comment: I figured out how to connect with razorsql (I think).  I'll try to figure this out and write up a good answer.  H2 seems to be an ideal lightweight db for *TWL*

Comment: Mathematica comes with a number of SQL servers on board. SQLite is one of them. Why not use that one?